# Segmentation faults in R's Cox regression with "exact" ties

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, cox-regression

I'm trying to fit a large discrete proportional-hazards model (~100k rows, ~10k events). To do this I used `coxph(..., method = "exact")` as recommended by the [survival package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) documentation, which states:

> The “exact partial likelihood” is equivalent to a conditional logistic model, and is appropriate when the times are a small set of discrete values.  If there are a large number of ties and (start, stop) style survival data the computational time will be excessive.

There were some warnings about computational difficulty with `coxph` and large numbers of ties, but according to the documentation for `clogit` in the same package:

> The computation of the exact partial likelihood can be very slow, however. If a particular strata had, say 10 events out of 20 subjects we have to add up a denominator that involves all possible ways of choosing 10 out of 20, which is 20!/(10!  10!)  = 184756 terms.  Gail et al describe a fast recursion method which largely ameleorates this;  it was incorporated into version 2.36-11 of the `survival` package.

So I didn't expect the computational issues to be too bad. Nevertheless, I've run into many segmentation faults when trying to fit variants of a trivial (one-predictor) Cox model on my dataset. One is a "C stack overflow," resulting in the short and sweet (and uninformative) message:

```
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
Execution halted
```

The other is a "memory not mapped" error, which occurred when I accidentally flipped the "event" boolean so that I had ~90k events instead of ~10k:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xffffffffac577830, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,     method = method, row.names(mf))
 2: coxph(Surv(time, status == EVENT.STATUS) ~ litter, data = data,     method = "exact")
aborting ...
```

For reference, the code I'm running is simply `coxph(Surv(t, d) ~ x, data = data, method = 'exact')`. `t` is an integer column, `d` is Boolean and `x` is a float.

Are these known issues? Are there workarounds?

EDIT: Here's some code reproducing the problem on the `rats` dataset (replicated 1000 times):

```
library(survival)
print("constructing data")
data <- rats
SIZE <- nrow(rats)
# passes with 100 reps, but fails with 100 on my machine (MacBook Pro, 16g RAM)
REPS <- 1000
# set to 0 for "memory not mapped", 1 for "C stack overflow"
EVENT.STATUS <- 0
data <- data[rep(seq_len(SIZE), REPS), ]
print(summary(data$status == EVENT.STATUS))
print("fitting model")
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status == EVENT.STATUS) ~ litter,
             data = data, method = "exact")
```

And here's `version`:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin14.0.0
system         x86_64, darwin14.0.0
status
major          3
minor          1.2
year           2014
month          10
day            31
svn rev        66913
language       R
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

Comment: can you reproduce with any of the datasets included in `survival` ? (use ` data(package='survival')` to list these)

Comment: Segfaults should prompt you to package up a reproducible example and send it (or them) to Terry Therneau. As far as I know he visits SO infrequently.

Comment: @BondedDust: thanks for the reminder. I'd also love to know if there are any possible workarounds until the bug gets fixed, though.

Comment: I thought about using `try` but that's not going to work with segfaults. Are you sure you need to use "exact"? The other proportional hazards models which are perhaps more appropriate for grouped data are Poisson-glm models.

Comment: Yes. The event data is discrete, so has large numbers of ties (only ~35 unique event times in 100k rows). I'm given to understand that Efron's and Breslow's approximations diverge substantially from the exact method in this case.

Comment: `try` would also not be helpful, even if it worked for segfaults, because I need to *actually train the model*, not just recover from the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to make a Poisson model with that dataset. (I've got a large dataset that I'm unwilling to risk a probable segfault on.)

```
fit <- glm(  I(status == 0) ~ litter +offset(log(time)), 
               data = data, family=poisson)

> fit

Call:  glm(formula = I(status == 0) ~ litter + offset(log(time)), family = poisson, 
    data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       litter  
  -4.706485    -0.003883  

Degrees of Freedom: 149999 Total (i.e. Null);  149998 Residual
Null Deviance:      60500 
Residual Deviance: 60150    AIC: 280200
```

This estimate of the effect of `litter` should be similar to what you would get from a Cox PH model.

If you want to see the "offset trick" documented, go to Breslow and Day's classic monograph: "Statistical Methods in Cancer Research; Vol II- The Design and Analysis of Cohort Studies". They used the GLIM software package, but the code is very similar to R's `glm` implementation, so the transport of concepts should be straightforward. (I had the opportunity to work briefly with Norm Breslow on my Masters thesis using GLIM. He was brilliant. I think it was my prior training with GLIM that made picking up R so easy.)

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't seen the Poisson-offset trick before. That's clever! Doesn't that model assume a constant hazard, though?

Comment: Yes it does, but  `coxph` assumes a constant relative hazard as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it seems the Poisson regression assumes that the *baseline* hazard function is constant, not just constant relative hazard (whereas Cox regression doesn't make any assumptions about the shape of the baseline hazard, although it does assume a constant hazard ratio between any two data points).

Comment: Right. That is the difference in the methods. You could construct models with piecewise variable hazards but you would need to segment the times and events into intervals.

Comment: Well, Prof. Thernau responded to my bug report saying that this number of ties would be computationally intractable even with the better `survival` code and the error was because it was trying to allocate more memory than my machine had. He recommended that I use the Efron approximation despite the large number of ties, so I'm marking this answer as correct-in-spirit (the spirit of "don't use the exact model").